# Environment variables in App Engine PHP runtime environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Are environment variables passed from `app.yaml` by any chance disabled in PHP runtime ?

The env variables seem correctly defined inside of the the 1.8.0 SDK runtime, but the never seem to get defined in the production runtime.

```
-- app.yaml --
application: some-app
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
  - url: /
    script: index.php

env_variables:
  APPLICATION_BASE: 'Application/'

-- index.php --
<?PHP
print_r($_SERVER);
print_r($_ENV);
```

SDK version works as expected: 
`$_ENV['APPLICATION_BASE']` and `$_SERVER['APPLICATION_BASE']` contain 'Application/'.

Production environment however, are not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No we haven't got this in yet - Can you file an issue in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3) and we'll get it done.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I filed the issue.